# Check if session logged is true

Tags: php

I have: header.php, register.php, login.php and profile.php

When the user is login in, I redirect him on profile.php using header(Location:profile.php)

Also, before I do that redirect I set a session:

```
$_SESSION['logged']= $user_email;
```

Using that, I would like to do a small trick on header.php, something like:

```
    if(($_SESSION['logged'] == true) {
         echo "<a href="profile.php"> Logo </a>"; 
    } 
    else {
         echo "<a href="index.php"> Logo </a>";
   }
```

Somehow, this isn't working. I'm missing something?

Comment: Your not closing your brackets properly. if(( should be if(

Comment: Show full code. (where is http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php ?)

Comment: You need [session_start()](http://id1.php.net/function.session-start).

Comment: session_start() is on the first line of header.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control session variable with [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) function

Try code below

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
  header("location:profile.php");
}
else{
  header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: That worked for my project. Now, I will check isset function on php.net. Thank you for help!